# Auto detect screen height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having the following code:

```
<img style="width:100%; height: ??? ;" id="FrontImg" src="Content/Img/Glow-Keyboard-Wallpaper-High-Resolution-Photos-445152.jpg" />
```

I wonder if there is som sort of way that with a script it autodetect users screen hight and then changes the "`height: ???;`" to the users screen hight.

Comment: You can do `height: 100%` too, you just need to also have set a height on every parent element of the `img` for it to work. A better method however would be to set the image to the background of a `width: 100%; height: 100%` div, as you can then use the `background-size: cover` property on it which will maintain the aspect ratio (ie. it won't stretch the image to fit)

Comment: You can use height:100vh (100% of users screen)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about the browser window, or the actual desktop screen?  If it's the former people have given you answers, if it's the latter you can't.

Comment: Furkan Basaran gave me the aswere that was 100% what i was looking for :)

Comment: @Rasmus May I just say, there is no reason to use jQuery for this, as it slows down your page and the overall experience for your users. Use css when it can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set height dynamicly with codes below:

```
$(function(){
    var height = $(window).height();
    $('#FrontImg').css("height", height + "px");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use : **vh** a css height unit (vertical height unit), 1 vh = 1% of the vertical height of the viewport.
It might not work on IE and Edge : see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Comment: Sidenote: Might not work in all browsers, see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewport units, like vh. For example:

```
img{
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
}
```

[Check browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)

But this will result in a distorted image.

A better way to do it is to use a container.

css:

```
.img_container{
    width:100%
    height:100vh;/*viewport unit*/
    background:url('url_to_your_image') no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```